# Python libraries to draw bit-field descriptions/ labels, as well as equations, as ASCII art in terminal?

Tags: python, ascii

I would like to do the following in Python: say, I have the binary number 0b11001010 - I would like to document/label its bits in the terminal. I'd imagine I could define the labels as an array of tuples like so:

```
bit_desc = [
  (1, "Most significant bit, 7"),
  (1, "Bit 6"),
  (0, "Bit 5"),
  (0, "Bit 4"),
  (1, "Bit 3"),
  (0, "Bit 2"),
  (1, "Bit 1"),
  (0, "Least significant bit, 0"),
]
```

... and get an output corresponding to it, for instance by calling some function like `print(format_bit_description_ascii(bit_desc, "This number main label"))` which looks like the following "ASCII art" in the terminal:

```
  11001010    This number main label
  ||||||||
  |||||||\--- Least significant bit, 0
  ||||||\---- Bit 1
  |||||\----- Bit 2
  ||||\------ Bit 3
  |||\------- Bit 4
  ||\-------- Bit 5
  |\--------- Bit 6
  \---------- Most significant bit, 7
```

I would love it if it would also be possible to "hide" (not draw) a line, if the description is empty.

Furthermore, I would also like to do the following in Python: define string which contains an equation in the LaTeX ([editor](https://latexeditor.lagrida.com/)), or a similar language like https://asciimath.org/ ; for instance:

```
formula_latex_str = "a = \frac{testval}{c}"
```

... and get something like this following output in terminal, as a result of a commend like for instance `print(format_equation_ascii(formula_latex_str))`:

```
     testval
a = ---------
        c
```

Is there anything like this out there? If not actual Python libraries - are there any kind of open-source command-line programs that would do something like this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149303/software-to-render-formulas-to-ascii-art lists several possibilities for formatting equations as ascii art: [tex2mail](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex2mail) Perl script, [Diagon](https://arthursonzogni.com/Diagon/) web application, and others